# usort order string by length optimization

Tags: php, performance, sorting

I'm coding a program in PHP that requires listing a big CSV file values ordered by string length.

I'm currently using:

```
if (($process = fopen($CSV_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    $CSV_array = array();
    while (($CSV_line = fgetcsv($process, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $CSV_array = array_merge($CSV_array,$CSV_line);
    }
    fclose($process);
}

usort($CSV_array, function($a,$b) {return mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a);});
```

Xdebug tells me that `usort` is taking almost half the computing time of the whole program (not displayed here).

Would you know any way to optimize that piece of code?

Comment: Are these typos: `$ CSV_array = array();`<- space; And: `mb_strlen($b[0]) - mb_strlen($a[0])` this is completely useless, basically it compares the lengh of  the first character of a with first character of b

Comment: Here is [mb-strlen documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php): see *Speed of mb_strlen varies a lot according to specified character set ...*. `mb_strlen($string, '8bit')` seems to be faster

Comment: The CSV I'm provided as well as the function of the program makes of my code a complex mix of arrays, and it's really not my choice. This code evaluates correctly the string length, but for anyone copying it I should have removed the [0] when refactoring it.


The spaces are just a typo, I'm working on improving my code quality so you can be assured that I'm already removing them from it.


Thank you for your suggestion fantaghirocco, I'll be trying that ASAP. Meanwhile, any other lead will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing the code too much, a first step would be a form of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```
$array = array_map(function ($str) { return array($str, mb_strlen($str)); }, $array);
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $b[1] - $a[1]; });
$array = array_map('current', $array);
```

This way you're not calling `mb_strlen` over and over again for every string.

Comment: Nice to bring that also into this question with the memoization. Tested your script with my test csv file and it also takes +/- half of the execution time from OP's original code.